# Cat filename.html returns weird text in centos 7

Tags: shell-script, centos-7

I have a `vishal.html` file, the content of the file is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a cool idea</.h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to read content using cat command, but when I tried `cat vishal.html` output is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
      <title></title>
      <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
      <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1671.6">
      <style type="text/css">
        p.p1 {
          margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px;
          line-height: 14.0px;
          font: 12.0px Helvetica;
          color: #000000;
          -webkit-text-stroke: #000000
        }

        span.s1 {
          font-kerning: none
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <p class="p1"><span class="s1">&lt;html&gt;</span></p>
      <p class="p1"><span class="s1">&lt;body&gt;</span></p>
      <p class="p1"><span class="s1">&lt;h1&gt;This is a cool
    idea&lt;/.h1&gt;</span></p>
      <p class="p1"><span class="s1">&lt;/body&gt;</span></p>
      <p class="p1"><span class="s1">&lt;/html&gt;</span></p>
      <p class="p1"><span class="s1"><br> </span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the expected output is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a cool idea</.h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Same works in Mac OS, but not sure why centos has this issue or am I missing somnething?

Comment: Where and how did you get that HTML file? Did you try to open that in any normal text editor?

Comment: i have created that file.i opened with text editor it is fine there @Biswapriyo

Comment: Does [Mac Users: Beware TextEdit “File Save…” issue](https://www.dummieshtml.com/2011/03/31/mac-users-beware-textedit-file-save-issue/) apply to this?

Comment: From the `content="Cocoa HTML Writer"` attribute, it seems that the editor is responsible for those additional metadata. Create the HTML in a simple text editor like `vi`.